# Dialog flickering and glitch when it open in android 9.0

Tags: android

I am opening dialog on click below android 9.0 there is no glitch or flickering while its opening but below android 8.0 and below its opening smoothly .

i tried to changes style with below but then also its not working

```
<style name="mystyle" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>



public Dialog displayInPaddedScreenDialog(Context context, View view, DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.mystyle);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.clubcard_Dialog;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        dialog.setContentView(view);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(onDismissListener);
        dialog.show();

        return dialog;
    }
```

i want in each version of android its should open smoothly without flickering  or glitch .